# A number is converted to NaN after some clicked to show in console - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a paging on list of products. When i clicked on "Next" button and show in console value of "tranght" (My code  only show value of "tranght") then type of "tranght" is converted to NaN. Help me, i'm newer in Jquery.

```js
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="${pageContext.request.contextPath }/js/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 var ds = [];
 var tranght = 1;
 var sobanghi = 0;
 var sotrang = 0;

 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#btnshow').click(function(){

   $.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    headers : {
     Accept : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     "Content-Type" : "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    },
    url : '${pageContext.request.contextPath }/findall.html',
    success : function(result) {
     ds = result.dssp;
     sobanghi = result.dssp.length;
     
     if ((sobanghi % 3) === 0){
      sotrang = Math.floor(sobanghi / 3);
     } else {
      sotrang = Math.floor(sobanghi / 3) + 1;
     }

     var s = "";
     s = s + "<table border=\"1\"><tr class=\"title\"><td>Ma sp</td><td>Ten sp</td><td>Gia</td><td>So luong</td><td>Ngay sx</td><td>Tinh trang</td><td>Mo ta</td><td>Hinh anh</td><td>Danh muc</td></tr>";
     for (var i=0; i<3; i++){
      s = s + "<tr><td>" + result.dssp[i].masp + "</td><td>" + result.dssp[i].tensp + "</td><td>" + result.dssp[i].gia + "</td><td>"+ result.dssp[i].soluong +"</td><td>"+ result.dssp[i].ngaysx + "</td><td>"+ result.dssp[i].tinhtrang +"</td><td>"+ result.dssp[i].mota +"</td><td>"+ result.dssp[i].hinhanh +"</td><td>"+ result.dssp[i].danhmuc.tendm +"</td></tr>" ;
     }
     s = s + "</table>";
     $('#result').html(s);

     var s1 = "<div class='prev'>Prev</div>";
     s1 += "<div class='index clicked'>" + 1 + "</div>";
     for (var i=2; i<=sotrang; i++){
      s1 += "<div class='index'>" + i + "</div>"; 
     } 
    
     s1 += "<div class='next'>Next</div>";
     $('#result1').html(s1);
    }
   });
  });

      //select a page
  $(".index").live('click', function(){

   $("#result1 > div").removeClass('clicked');
   $(this).addClass('clicked');

   tranght = parseInt($(this).html());

   var startpoint = (tranght - 1)*3; 
   var endpoint = startpoint + 3;
   sobanghi = ds.length
   if (endpoint > sobanghi){
    endpoint = sobanghi;
   }

   var s = "";
   s = s + "<table border=\"1\"><tr class=\"title\"><td>Ma sp</td><td>Ten sp</td><td>Gia</td><td>So luong</td><td>Ngay sx</td><td>Tinh trang</td><td>Mo ta</td><td>Hinh anh</td><td>Danh muc</td></tr>";
   for (var i=startpoint; i<endpoint; i++){
    s = s + "<tr><td>" + ds[i].masp + "</td><td>" + ds[i].tensp + "</td><td>" + ds[i].gia + "</td><td>"+ ds[i].soluong +"</td><td>"+ ds[i].ngaysx + "</td><td>"+ ds[i].tinhtrang +"</td><td>"+ ds[i].mota +"</td><td>"+ ds[i].hinhanh +"</td><td>"+ ds[i].danhmuc.tendm +"</td></tr>" ;
   }
   s = s + "</table>";
   $('#result').html(s);
  });

      // click "next" button

  $(".next").live('click', function(){
   console.log("value of tranght: " + tranght);
   console.log("Type of: " + typeof tranght);
   if (tranght === sotrang){
    tranght = sotrang;
    console.log("Type of: " + typeof tranght);
   } else {
    tranght = parseInt(tranght,6) + 1;
    console.log("value: " + tranght);
    console.log("Type of: " + typeof tranght);
   }
  });

 });

</script>
```

Comment: This is a lot of code. Please try to boil it down to something more reasonable, with only the relevant parts.

Comment: What are you shooting for with a radix of 6 when calling parseInt()?

Comment: sorry, i try it when that error happend. original: tranght = parseInt(tranght) + 1;

Comment: @Ed Cottrell: How to i boil it down, i can't find edit menu?

Comment: @abc There should be an edit link directly beneath your question, toward the left side.

Answer (score 0):

We are missing some code, is the html object with the class 'index' an input? if so, you need to change

```
tranght = parseInt($(this).html());
```

to

```
tranght = parseInt($(this).val());
```

to capture the value and not the content.

Comment: tks for your help, but i click "next" button only (in code : $(".next").live('click', function()). When i change as you and result alert(tranght) is NaN